# Exponential generating series of binomial coefficients: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{ k \choose j}\frac{x^k}{k!} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis, generating-functions

I'm wondering if anyone knows what it is? The exponential generating series I have in mind is
$$
f_j(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty { k \choose j} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}.
$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may just write

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty { k \choose j} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=j}^\infty { k \choose j} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=j}^\infty \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}=\frac{x^j}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^\infty \frac{x^{(k-j)}}{(k-j)!}=\frac{x^j}{j!}e^x.
> $$